# Is there a generic dummy command?

Tags: latex-base

I would like to add in the title field of some bib entries a dummy command which I can redefine to force e.g. a linebreak in certain cases. I need a command which normally doesn't do anything, doesn't rely on some specific package (so that the bib-file doesn't break when used without the package), which isn't used elsewhere and which I can safely redefine without breaking something.

I looked up latex.ltx but couldn't find anything suitable. Has someone an idea what I could use if I don't want to clutter the bib with `\csname adummycommand\endcsname`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer no.

Longer answer, as an alternative to the slightly obscure

```
\csname adummycommand\endcsname
```

You could use

```
\adummy
```

together with

```
@PREAMBLE{{\providecommand\adummy{}}}
```

Comment: That would be quite okay but biblatex/biber don't like `@PREAMBLE{\providecommand\adummy{}}`. I get `syntax error: found "dummy"`.

Comment: I usually redefine some command before/after `\printindex`, `\tableofcontents`, `\bibliography` etc. It suits me well for forcing line breaks. For rather complicated things I define two independent commands for the same typesetted material. The disadvantage is it can lead to mistyping errors.

Comment: @Malipivo that's fine in a personal project but harder to arrange if you are publishing "public" bib databases

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I put to much trust in your example ;-). Even with bibtex it wouldn't work: There is a layer of braces missing. One needs to use `@PREAMBLE{{\providecommand\adummy{}}}` or `@PREAMBLE{"\providecommand\adummy{}"}`. With this correction it works with biber too. And the definition is seen by the document. Now I only have to think about a good name ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oops I fixed the answer;-)